# View with different height and width calculation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to implement an algorithm, where we have 2 view and want to matched with their CGPoint.
For example - I have one view with 300:400 (wight : height) and another view with 200:300(wight : 
 height). Now on 1st view i am drawing a circle with touch move and send all CGPoint to another view once touch End or vice versa, But as both view has different resolution circle is not getting and same points. How can we fixed that

For draw Canvas

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     // Drawing code
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
    for (NSDictionary *pointdict in _pointArrays) {
        if([pointdict[@"point"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            UIColor *clo = (UIColor*)pointdict[@"color"];
              CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, 
              clo.CGColor);
              CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt);
              [pointdict[@"point"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id 
               object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
               {
                  CGPoint point = [object CGPointValue];
                  if(idx == 0){
                      CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, 
                       point.y);
                  }else{
                      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, 
                      point.y);
                  }
              }];
               CGContextStrokePath(context);
         }
      }
   }
```

For UI Touch Event
       Touch Start

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent 
   *)event{
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
        if(_isDrawSelected){
             NSDictionary *dict = @{@"color" : [self getSelectedColor] 
           , @"point" : @[[NSValue 
              valueWithCGPoint:point]],@"Isedited" : @NO};
             [_pointArrays addObject:dict];
          }
    }
```

Touch Move

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent 
   *)event{
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    if(_isDrawSelected){
            NSMutableArray *pointArray = [NSMutableArray 
           arrayWithCapacity:0];
       NSDictionary* points = [[_pointArrays lastObject] mutableCopy];
       if([points[@"point"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            for (id po in points[@"point"]){
                [pointArray addObject:po];
            }
     }
       [_pointArrays removeLastObject];
       [pointArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
       [points setValue:pointArray forKey:@"point"];
       [_pointArrays addObject:points];
        pointArray = nil;
        points = nil;
       [self setNeedsDisplay];
   }
}
```

Touch End

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent 
  *)event{
       // Sending Notification to other view
      [[NSNotificationCenter 
       defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kreannotatePoint object:nil 
       userInfo:@{@"drowPoint" : [_pointArrays lastObject], @"size" : 
      @(self.bounds.size)}];
 }
```

Other View will receive the notification and process drawing

```
-(void)updateReannotation:(NSDictionary*_Nonnull)value{
      NSMutableArray *pointArray = [NSMutableArray 
      arrayWithCapacity:0];
      for (NSDictionary* po in value[@"point"]){
         CGPoint point = CGPointMake([po[@"xAxis"] floatValue], 
         [po[@"yAxis"] floatValue]);
        [pointArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
    }
     NSDictionary *dict = @{@"color" : [self 
        getcolorFromString:value[@"color"]] , @"point" : 
        pointArray,@"Isedited" : @NO};
       [_pointArrays addObject:dict];
        pointArray = nil;
      [self setNeedsDisplay];
  }
```

Other view also used above method to draw and send notification to previous view.

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Code for draw circle or CGPoint calculation code.

Comment: @jayprakash everything that is related.

Comment: To draw a circle i am using Canvas view - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect using UI touch events for draw, Storing all CGPoint on UITouch Move .

Comment: @keshu R , I am searching code or idea for my solution, where i can calculate.

Comment: @jayprakash - Do you want to convert and save translated points? Or do you just want it drawn to the smaller scale?

Comment: I just want to draw, Basically when i am drawing with finger move its is correct position, But when i am sending same point to other view or vice versa its issue. Because if resolution are different to each other.

Comment: @DonMag with my above code, I am able to draw but its different point location. Here i am explaining little more, Suppose i have one view of 300x400 and on that i am showing one image, On that image i have on black point on position support xAxis- 30 and yAxis 40, Now i have marker a circle. In other view has 200x300 and i have plot same image and based on this view my Black mark has position xAxis- 28 and yAxis 37. once we plot that privies point its mismatched. I want its show be correct mark.

Comment: @DonMag Hope its more clear, I am looking to modify the drawable point based on view resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try scaling y and x axis with ratios. For example if you are moving a point  (60,100) of 300x400 rectangle to 300x200 rectangle, you scale x axis by 60x300/300 and 100x200/400 and plot your point.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* take the approach of simply translating the coordinates. So, for each point, you would do:

```
point.x *= secondViewWidth / firstViewWidth;
point.y *= secondViewHeight / firstViewHeight;
```

You would also (likely) want to calculate a change for the lineWidth. Not very noticeable between `300 x 400` and `200 x 300` sizes, but it would become **very** noticeable if your views were `300 x 400` and, say, `80 x 120`.

This could (or *would*) make the drawing code a bit more complex.

Another approach - which might be more desirable - would be to use `CGAffineTransformScale` for the `secondView`. No translating points, no calculating line widths, only one block of code for drawing, etc.

Here is an example. I modified your `CanvasView` code a little bit. Mainly, returning red and blue for the drawing colors (since you didn't provide the methods you were using), and changing this method:

```
-(void)updateReannotation:(NSDictionary*_Nonnull)value { ... }
```

to:

```
-(void)updateReannotation:(NSNotification * _Nonnull)notif { ... }
```

since your actual data needs to be pulled out of the notification's `.userInfo`.

No `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections, so just use these files and assign a view controller's class to `CanvasTestViewController`:

**CanvasView.h**

```
//
//  CanvasView.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 2/27/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface CanvasView : UIView

- (void)enableDrawing:(BOOL)b;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**CanvasView.m**

```
//
//  CanvasView.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 2/27/20.
//

#import "CanvasView.h"

@interface CanvasView()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pointArrays;
@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL isDrawSelected;

@end

@implementation CanvasView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) commonInit {
    _pointArrays = [NSMutableArray array];
    _isDrawSelected = NO;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
    for (NSDictionary *pointdict in _pointArrays) {
        if([pointdict[@"point"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            UIColor *clo = (UIColor*)pointdict[@"color"];
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, clo.CGColor);
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt);
            [pointdict[@"point"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                CGPoint point = [object CGPointValue];
                if(idx == 0){
                    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                }else{
                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                }
            }];
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
        }
    }
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    if(_isDrawSelected){
        NSDictionary *dict = @{@"color" : [self getSelectedColor],
                               @"point" : @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]],
                               @"Isedited" : @NO
        };
        [_pointArrays addObject:dict];
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    if(_isDrawSelected){
        NSMutableArray *pointArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
        NSDictionary* points = [[_pointArrays lastObject] mutableCopy];
        if([points[@"point"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            for (id po in points[@"point"]) {
                [pointArray addObject:po];
            }
        }
        [_pointArrays removeLastObject];
        [pointArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
        [points setValue:pointArray forKey:@"point"];
        [_pointArrays addObject:points];
        pointArray = nil;
        points = nil;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(_isDrawSelected){
        // Sending Notification to other view
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"kreannotatePoint"
         object:nil
         userInfo:@{
             @"drowPoint" : [_pointArrays lastObject],
             @"size" : @(self.bounds.size)
         }];
    }
}

// for demo purposes, just return red
- (UIColor *)getSelectedColor {
    return [UIColor redColor];
}

// for demo purposes, just return blue
- (UIColor *)getcolorFromString:(NSString *)v {
    return [UIColor blueColor];
}

-(void)updateReannotation:(NSNotification * _Nonnull)notif {

    NSDictionary *value = notif.userInfo[@"drowPoint"];

    NSDictionary *dict = @{
        @"color" : [self getcolorFromString:value[@"color"]],
        @"point" : value[@"point"],
        @"Isedited" : @NO
    };

    [_pointArrays addObject:dict];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)enableDrawing:(BOOL)b {
    _isDrawSelected = b;
    if (!_isDrawSelected) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateReannotation:) name:@"kreannotatePoint" object:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

**CanvasTestViewController.h**

```
//
//  CanvasTestViewController.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 2/27/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface CanvasTestViewController : UIViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**CanvasTestViewController.m**

```
//
//  CanvasTestViewController.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 2/27/20.
//

#import "CanvasTestViewController.h"
#import "CanvasView.h"

@interface CanvasTestViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CanvasView *topView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CanvasView *botView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *containerView;

@end

CGFloat topWidth = 300.0;
CGFloat topHeight = 400.0;

CGFloat botWidth = 200.0;
CGFloat botHeight = 300.0;

@implementation CanvasTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // CGAffineTransformScale scales to the center of the view
    // by using a "container" view for the bottom view, it's much
    // easier to maintain the "target" frame
    [self setupWithContainer];

    // without a container view, we also have to change the
    // anchor point on the bottom view to keep the frame at its original position
    //[self setupWithoutContainer];

}

- (void)setupWithContainer {

    // create topView
    self.topView = [CanvasView new];
    self.topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

    // using auto-layout
    self.topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // create botView
    self.botView = [CanvasView new];
    self.botView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    // using auto-layout
    self.botView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // create containerView
    self.containerView = [UIView new];
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    // using auto-layout
    self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // add botView to containerView
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.botView];

    // add views to self.view
    [self.view addSubview:self.topView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.containerView];

    // respect safeArea
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

        // constrain topView to safeArea Top + 8-pts
        [self.topView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:8.0],

        // constrain topView centerX
        [self.topView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerXAnchor],

        // constrain topView Width, Height
        [self.topView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:topWidth],
        [self.topView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:topHeight],

        // constrain containerView Top to topView Bottom + 20-pts
        [self.containerView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topView.bottomAnchor constant:20.0],

        // constrain containerView centerX to topView centerX
        [self.containerView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topView.centerXAnchor],

        // constrain containerView Width, Height
        [self.containerView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:botWidth],
        [self.containerView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:botHeight],

        // constrain botView centerX, centerY to containerView centerX, centerY
        [self.botView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.containerView.centerXAnchor],
        [self.botView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.containerView.centerYAnchor],

        // constrain botView Width, Height to same as topView
        [self.botView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:topWidth],
        [self.botView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:topHeight],

    ]];

    // target scaled size for botView
    CGFloat wScale = botWidth / topWidth;
    CGFloat hScale = botHeight / topHeight;

    // scale the bottom view
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, wScale, hScale);
    [self.botView setTransform:t];

    // allow drawing on the top view
    [self.topView enableDrawing:YES];

    // don't allow drawing on the bottom view
    // (also sets the bottom view as the notification receiver)
    [self.botView enableDrawing:NO];

}

- (void)setupWithoutContainer {

    // create topView
    self.topView = [CanvasView new];
    self.topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

    // using auto-layout
    self.topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // create botView
    self.botView = [CanvasView new];
    self.botView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    // using auto-layout
    self.botView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // add views to self.view
    [self.view addSubview:self.topView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.botView];

    // respect safeArea
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

        // constrain topView to safeArea Top + 8-pts
        [self.topView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:8.0],

        // constrain topView centerX
        [self.topView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerXAnchor],

        // constrain topView Width, Height
        [self.topView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:topWidth],
        [self.topView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:topHeight],

        // constrain botView Top to topView Bottom + 20-pts
        [self.botView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topView.bottomAnchor constant:20.0],

        // constrain botView centerX to topView centerX
        [self.botView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topView.centerXAnchor],

        // constrain botView Width, Height to same as topView
        [self.botView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:topWidth],
        [self.botView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:topHeight],

    ]];

    // target scaled size for botView
    CGFloat wScale = botWidth / topWidth;
    CGFloat hScale = botHeight / topHeight;

    // CGAffineTransformScale scales from the center of the view (0.5,0.5)
    // so calculate anchor point to keep the top at its original position
    // if our views are not horizontally centered, we'd also need to calculate
    // the xAnchor adjustment
    CGFloat yAnchor = 0.5 / hScale;
    [self.botView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, yAnchor)];

    // scale the bottom view
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, wScale, hScale);
    [self.botView setTransform:t];

    // allow drawing on the top view
    [self.topView enableDrawing:YES];

    // don't allow drawing on the bottom view
    // (also sets the bottom view as the notification receiver)
    [self.botView enableDrawing:NO];

}

@end
```

Result:

[image]

Couple notes:

- The view controller has "top" and "bottom" view widths and heights as variables, so you can easily play with the sizes to see how it looks.
- As you'll see, there are two very similar approaches for setting up the views. My preferred approach is the `setupWithContainer` vs `setupWithoutContainer`. When scaling a view, it defaults to scaling from the center. Embedding the "canvas" view in a "container" view makes it much easier to manage the location of the frame.
- **Aspect-ratio** ... that is, suppose your firstView ends up being `400 x 400` (square, `1:1` ratio) and your second view is `300 x 100` (wide, flat `3:1` ratio), the "replicated drawing" will "stretch". A round circle in firstView will end up being a wide, flat oval in the secondView. You didn't indicate in your post anything about that, so I didn't take that into account.
- There should be enough comments in the code to explain what's going on.

*Caveat:* This should be considered ***example*** code, not ***production ready*** code. There's no error-handling or sanity checks.

---

**EDIT**

To use *calculated scaling* instead of Transforms requires very few changes, and would make it easier to accomplish your "cross platform" objectives.

Here is an updated `DrawRect` method in `CanvasView` class:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt);

    for (NSDictionary *pointdict in _pointArrays) {

        CGFloat xScale = 1.0;
        CGFloat yScale = 1.0;

        CGSize sourceSize = [pointdict[@"size"] CGSizeValue];

        // if sourceSize == CGSizeZero, we are actively drawing
        //  else, we were sent points (and a size) from "the other guy"
        if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(sourceSize, CGSizeZero)) {

            // calculate scaling based on selfSize : sourceSize
            xScale = self.bounds.size.width / sourceSize.width;
            yScale = self.bounds.size.height / sourceSize.height;

            // scale the lineWidth (if desired)
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0 * MIN(xScale, yScale));
        }

        if([pointdict[@"point"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            UIColor *clo = (UIColor*)pointdict[@"color"];
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, clo.CGColor);
            [pointdict[@"point"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                CGPoint point = [object CGPointValue];
                point.x *= xScale;
                point.y *= yScale;
                if(idx == 0){
                    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                }else{
                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                }
            }];
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

For each `pointdict` dictionary, get the `size` value. If it is not zero, it will be the size sent by the active drawing view, so:

- calculate scale values, and
- translate / convert each point coordinate

I've posted a full example project here: https://github.com/DonMag/CanvasDraw

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But my case is different, In my case just suppose one end has iPAD and other end has iPhone, Now iPhone editing over canvas and sending through push notification to ipad or vice versa, Other device receiving push notification, its send NSNotification to that class where canvas suppose to draw, Now in that case my canvas draw point getting missed matched. Hope now its more clear.

Comment: You can still use this approach. On your "receiving device" you just need to implement `CGAffineTransformScale` for your "target" view.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag Basically what I am looking is that one user on iPhone and another user on android any phone. Now there  are exchanging their draw point through server, once android draw a canvas and send (x-cordinate and y-cordinate) to server other end iPhone will receive and draw point (x-cordinate and y-cordinate) same. Bothe device has same image and drawing their exchange point on same image but different device. I have tried both solution , its not helping in case on different device, Its help is both end has same device.

Comment: @jayprakash - Are you still working on this? I can give you a solution for different devices.

Comment: Yes Actually Its working perfect with iPhone to any iPhone and iPad , But when Android or window come in picture and share there coordinate, Its not perfect. I have tried with different solutions well. Basically I am trying a common algorithm where I can matched perfect coordinate.

Comment: @jayprakash - see the EDIT at the bottom of my answer.